# RESTful service in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, rest

I am new to CodeIgniter, I want to build restful webservices using CodeIgniter. How can I post data to mysql and fetch from it back using REST services? I have gone through a web site 'tutplus', but it is explained there without mysql database.

Comment: database is not `REST Server` part, you should read more about CI `db` library on codeigniter site https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, create some controllers, for example: **user.php**
At this controller write all necessary methods, exp: *getUserInfo(), getUser(), getAge()* and call these methods via URL.
To deal with this suggest:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually on the project that i'm working on, we use RESTControllers, there's a project out there on github which extends codeigniter controller with all the REST capabilities:
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

All you need to do in your code it's include the file on the controller and extend that new controller:

```
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');  
class system extends REST_Controller {

}
```

You could also include the REST controller on the autoload libraries confinguration.
This library opens the 4 basic REST API as the GET, POST, PUT and DELETE

In your code the controller url should be declarated as this, so you would get a POST method on the index

```
public function index_post()
{
    // ...just some code example
    $this->response($book, 201); // Send an HTTP 201 Created
}
```

If you need a get on the index, you declare it as a GET method:

```
public function index_get()
{
    // ...just some code example
    $this->response($book, 201); // Send an HTTP 201 Created
}
```